# AWS ECS upgrade to new task definitions kills long running outgoing connections

Tags: amazon-web-services, celery, amazon-ecs

We are using [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) for asynchronous tasks that keep a connection open to a remote server. These Celery jobs can run for up to 10 minutes.

When we deploy a new version of our code, AWS ECS won't wait for these jobs to be ready, so it kills the instances with the Celery workers before they are ready.

One solution is to tell Celery to retry it if it failed, but that could potentially cause other problems.

Is there a way to avoid this? Can we instruct AWS ECS to wait for completion of outgoing connections? Any other way to approach this?

Comment: The ECS agent stops the tasks with a `docker stop` command, which sends a [SIGTERM](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_StopTask.html) to the job running in the container with a 30 seconds timeout (which can be [increased](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-config.html)). If you run the application with the `ENTRYPOINT` directive, you can intercept the `SIGTERM` and start cleanup operations before the task exits. That, at least, wouldn't kill the celery jobs unexpectedly. Is that something that would work for you?

Comment: @JoséAntonioHaroPeralta that sounds like a plan. Will have to experiment with it to see how it will work, but this is the best idea we have so far. Thanks